# Python: wingIDE syntax highlighting customization

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, wing-ide

I'm using the free version of [wingIDE](http://www.wingware.com/). I am trying to customize individual syntax highlighting colors (comments, strings, constants, normal text, etc). I see the generic color changes for 'background,selected text", etc, but nothing that lets me get down to specifics. Is this a limitation of the free version or is the option hidden deep in the UI? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now available in the free version 6.0.8-2 (probably one or two releases after yours, PPTim...).

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring. From here you can alter each type. I use the 'Solarized - Dark' color palette (set this in the User Interface menu, at the very top of the Preferences window) which can make open string highlights difficult to read. In the Syntax Coloring view, this is 'stringeol'. I've altered the background to Black Pearl. For a list of other colour names and descriptions, see the [Wing IDE documentation](https://wingware.com/doc/custom/syntax).